# Как "превратить" string в byte?

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь "работать" с типом byte.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

```
message.setMessage = (byte)Console.ReadLine();
```

на эту строку выдаёт ошибку

```
tehn1_old.cs(73,48): error CS0030: Cannot convert type `string' to `byte'
```

Попробовал добавить:

```
message.setMessage = (byte)(int)Console.ReadLine();
```

Таже "чехарда":

```
tehn1_old.cs(73,53): error CS0030: Cannot convert type `string' to `int'
```

Comment: Нельзя конвертировать `string` в числовой тип, ибо это даже не родственные типы + не было означено пользовательского преобразования. Здесь нужен парсинг, так что используйте `{typename}.TryParse` (`byte.TryParse` например).

Comment: И да, в `C#` используйте, пожалуйста, общепринятый PascalCase, а не camelCase (и тем более snake_case).

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Обычно действительно используется `PascalCase`, но для приваных полей и внутренних временных переменных не запрещается (а иногда и рекомендуется) использовать `camelCase`. Лично я приватные поля еще и выделяю префиксом подчеркивания, например: `_camelCase` .

Comment: @ГеннадийП, спасибо за экскурс, я в курсе :) (кстати, \_something не относится ни к Pascal-, ни к camel- case'y, ибо написание "\_" не зависит от регистра) Обратите внимание, что `setMessage` точно не является приватным, а также взгляните на название проекта, которое является пространством имён по умолчанию.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Согласен, здесь я прослакал. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Попробуйте так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11539739/5909792):

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine());
```

Больше информации о [Encoding.UTF8 Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.utf8?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_Encoding_UTF8)